# GCP Cloud Run Flask app starting but not publishing data?

Tags: docker, flask, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn, google-cloud-run

I have a Cloud Run service that operates as follows:

1. Health check connects to "/" endpoint, flask detects this and redirects to "/start".
2. connection made to "/start", this starts an asynchronous main() function.
3. the main function has a websocket client connect to a 3rd party server and wait for data.

Locally (Windows PC) and in a docker linux environment this works correctly. However, when pushed to Cloud Run, the health check passes and gunicorn starts, but I never see the main function start.

I've tried both print statements and Google logs, but neither print from Cloud Run, only locally. Not even any error statements. Gunicorn receives a "term" signal and shuts down after a few minutes, but the Cloud Run service will continue to run. Gunicorn will not restart.
EDIT: I've also run it in the Cloud Run emulator, runs perfectly fine.

Here is the python code (summarized for privacy reasons):

```
import asyncio
import os
import json
#import pytz
from datetime import datetime
from websockets.client import connect
from websockets.exceptions import ConnectionClosed
from flask import Flask, redirect
from google.cloud import logging

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def health_check():
    return redirect('/start')

@app.route('/start')
def start():
    asyncio.run(main())

async def format_message(data):
    #code for formatting and publishing data to pubsub Topic

async def main():
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + os.environ["API_KEY"],
        "Sec-WebSocket-Version": "13",
        "Connection": "Upgrade",
        "Upgrade": "websocket",
        "Host": "3rdparty:443"
    }
    
    async for websocket in connect(uri="wss://3rdparty:443/v1/stream?cid=our_host&type=message",      extra_headers=headers):
        try:
            print("socket started", flush=True)

            while True:
                message = await websocket.recv()
                await format_message(message)

        except ConnectionClosed as e:
            print(f"Connection closed: {type(e).__name__}: {e}", flush=True)
            
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {type(e).__name__}: {e}", flush=True)
```

here is my gunicorn config:

```
import os

workers = int(os.environ.get('GUNICORN_PROCESSES', '2'))

threads = int(os.environ.get('GUNICORN_THREADS', '4'))

bind = f"{os.environ.get('HOSTNAME', '127.0.0.1')}:{os.environ.get('PORT', '3000')}"

forwarded_allow_ips = '*'

secure_scheme_headers = { 'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https' }
```

and here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10

API_KEY=SECRET_KEY \
PORT=8080 \
HOSTNAME=0.0.0.0 \
GUNICORN_THREADS=4 \
GUNICORN_PROCESSES=2 \
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE

EXPOSE 8080

COPY . /hsrb-proofpoint-pod-email-eds-avalon

WORKDIR /hsrb-proofpoint-pod-email-eds-avalon

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "--config", "config.py", "main:app"]
```

Comment: Are you expecting the health check to follow the redirect to `/start`? AFAIK, health checks do not follow redirects. If you want to schedule HTTP GET requests to your endpoint, use Cloud Scheduler.

Comment: I'm not python expert and asyncio is mysterious for me. But are you trying to start something in background? Cloud Run throttle the CPU outside the request context (however websockets are supported and works well)